# displacement between 2 images

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I would like to ask a question about normalized cross correlation.

Indeed,the steps of calculation of normalized cross correlation (NCC) are :

1. Calculation of FFT or convolution
2. Calculation of local sums

The formula of NCC is available in the bottom of this documentation https://fr.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/normxcorr2.html

In the first step, I took (it's an example):

a =

```
0.4693    0.2015    0.3220    0.8843
0.9090    0.1872    0.7254    0.8845
0.6666    0.6917    0.4871    0.3952
0.1845    0.9348    0.2403    0.9641
```

b =

```
0.5244    0.0120    0.0678    0.8644
0.4334    0.1436    0.4166    0.7587
0.8684    0.7909    0.5884    0.9340
0.4638    0.0562    0.5183    0.6035
```

Then
a2 =

```
0.4693    0.2015    0.3220    0.8843         0         0
0.9090    0.1872    0.7254    0.8845         0         0
0.6666    0.6917    0.4871    0.3952         0         0
0.1845    0.9348    0.2403    0.9641         0         0
     0         0         0         0         0         0
     0         0         0         0         0         0
```

b2 =

```
0.5244    0.0120    0.0678    0.8644         0         0
0.4334    0.1436    0.4166    0.7587         0         0
0.8684    0.7909    0.5884    0.9340         0         0
0.4638    0.0562    0.5183    0.6035         0         0
     0         0         0         0         0         0
     0         0         0         0         0         0
```

I found :

conv2(rot90(a,2),b)

ans =

```
0.5055    0.1376    0.5584    0.9575    0.2733    0.8205    0.1595
0.6250    0.5028    1.2366    1.7782    1.0741    1.4291    0.7161
1.4722    1.6299    2.2702    4.1249    2.3243    2.0076    1.4637
1.6373    1.5220    2.8883    5.0546    3.0854    2.4246    1.8292
1.3345    1.8440    2.3115    4.0665    2.5920    1.8209    1.6073
1.1781    1.3650    1.5358    2.9240    1.3762    1.0484    0.9869
0.4101    0.1990    0.5698    0.9295    0.3251    0.3648    0.2832
```

conv2(rot90(a2,2),b2)

ans =

```
     0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0
     0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0
     0         0    0.5055    0.1376    0.5584    0.9575    0.2733    0.8205    0.1595         0         0
     0         0    0.6250    0.5028    1.2366    1.7782    1.0741    1.4291    0.7161         0         0
     0         0    1.4722    1.6299    2.2702    4.1249    2.3243    2.0076    1.4637         0         0
     0         0    1.6373    1.5220    2.8883    5.0546    3.0854    2.4246    1.8292         0         0
     0         0    1.3345    1.8440    2.3115    4.0665    2.5920    1.8209    1.6073         0         0
     0         0    1.1781    1.3650    1.5358    2.9240    1.3762    1.0484    0.9869         0         0
     0         0    0.4101    0.1990    0.5698    0.9295    0.3251    0.3648    0.2832         0         0
     0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0
     0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0
```

So, adding zeros will not change the result of FFT /convolution. But after calculating local sums, the result changes because it takes into consideration the size of a (or a2). (`normxcorr2(a,b)` is different from `normxcorr2(a2,b2)`)

So when I want to calculate the displacement between two grayscale images using cross correlation, the result is not the same than if I translated the image (by padding with zeros)

Could you explain me why the displacement changes even if the translation (padding) is the same?

Comment: How do you calculate `a2` and `b2`?

Comment: @m7913d I pad `a` and `b` by `a2=padarray(a,[2 2 ],'post')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like an edge effect.

Consider two images a and b where blue has a value of 0.5 and red has a value of 0.25.

[image]

If you were to perform a phase correlation between the two images, you would find that image a had been translated one unit in the x direction and 1 unit in the y direction with a normalized correlation value of 1 (perfect match!).

However, consider now adding a border of 0s around images a and b to produce images A and B:

[image]

Doing a phase correlation around these images will result in a 0 shift in the x direction and a 0 shift in the the y direction BUT the normalized correlation value will not be 1.  In fact the normalized correlation value is 0.708254. This makes sense because the phase correlation is matching the border of the images.

There are plenty of ways around this, for instance applying a hamming window, that I won't get into.

This wikipedia article is a great reference too (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_correlation)

Good luck and let me know if you my answer is at all confusing.

Comment: Thank you ! it helped me to understand more the problem !